# Wheelnav menu with Text and Icon

Tags: wheelnav.js

I need to develop a wheelnav menu with text and icons together in the menu items. Is it possible to make the menu with text and icon? Please help me to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Currently (v1.7.1) wheelnav.js supports only one type of navItem. It can be text, icon or image.

You can achieve your needs with SVG/PNG/JPG images. I suggest that you create an SVG file with icon and text and use it in your wheelnav.

```
wheel.createWheel(["imgsrc:icon_text_1.svg", "imgsrc:icon_text_2.svg", "imgsrc:icon_text_3.svg"]);
```